# Is copper DWV "hard-temper" pipe type M?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, copper-tubing, terminology, copper-pipe

I was looking at an FNPT copper adapter online (*1-1/2 in. Copper DWV Cup x FIP Female Adapter Fitting*) which says "Use with DWV hard-temper tubing" and I'm not sure what **hard-temper tubing** refers to, but thought it might be referring to type M.  Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

M, L, & K are all hard-temper (not soft/bendable/coiled) of different wall thicknesses (M being the thinnest & thus cheapest.)

Unless you're caught in one of the "the plumbers union got the state board to mandate more profit for them" places I would never choose copper for DWV. It's expensive, and it rots out over time; plastic DWV pipes are cheap and laugh at corrosive drain cleaners, etc.

Comment: It's already there, from the late 1940s. I was thinking of adding an AAV since the drain pipe goes down into the concrete floor and connects to the 4" DWV well below the trap weir. https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/plumbing/maximum-length-for-fixture-drains_o